# How do I design "Show all Dupicate items"?

Tags: web-app, layout, validation, ux-designer

There is an input field we need user to input a name in, and as they enter the name, system checks if there is a duplicate name and if there is, it will be shown under the input box.

Currently, we show 3 items at once along with a "Show all" button.  On clicking, that button will show 20 items at the maximum. I'm updating this design now. I tried to use a modal to show all duplicate items. I also tried to use a scrollbar on the right side of duplicate items.

Is there any better way to do this?

This is a simple draft of our app:
[image]

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. When you say duplicate, do you mean exact duplicates or a name containing the entered name. I ask this because if I entered "Joe" and I am shown 20 more entries which say "Joe", how would that help me?

Also, if you are allowing duplicate entries, what is the purpose of showing the duplicates?

Comment: Similar Question: [How to tell users that s/he might be adding a duplicate record](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/107676/how-to-tell-users-that-s-he-might-be-adding-a-duplicate-record)

Comment: @ShreyasTripathy Hi, in this question I mean a name containing the entered name. In our app, we allow duplicate names but they may have different information. We show the duplicated items to know if the user really wants to create a new name or can choose from the existing name. Thanks!

Comment: How many possible “duplicates” could there be? May it make sense to only start showing duplicates when one has entered a minimum number of characters, or use a button or Enter key for instance? Is user more likely to be searching for an existing record or trying to create a new one? Is there a single input field or may there be several (e.g. first name, last name, e-mail…)?